# Promises not resolving or rejecting

Tags: javascript, promise, q, web-worker

I am trying to get the `promises` to resolve correctly,while debugging the `worker`,the worker sends the payload using `onmessage`.

I create a worker using a `singleton`,the `callWorker` creates a `promise` which is resolved in `onmessage`.

```
 var checkIntersectionWithAllLayers = function checkIntersectionWithAllLayers(rectFeature) {

       var callWorker = function callWorker(layerLabel) {

             var deferred = Q.defer();

            var payload = {
                type: 'start',
                payload: {
                    features: layerInfo.getAt(layerLabel).data.toGeoJSON().features,
                    rectFeature: rectFeature,
                    layerLabel: layerLabel
                }
            };
            worker.onmessage = function getIntersectingFeatures(e) {

                if (e.data.type === 'rectangle_query_worker_result') {
                    var result = e.data.result;
                    console.log("The result for layerLabel", result.layerLabel, "is ", result);
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }
            };
            worker.postMessage(payload);
            return deferred.promise;
        };

    var promises = _(layerInfo.get())
                      .pluck('layerLabel')
                      .filter(layerData.isLayerChecked)
                      .map(callWorker)
                      .thru(Q.all)
                      .value();

    return promises;
};
```

I use the promises like this:

```
var resolveIntersections = function resolveIntersections(intersections) {

    console.log("The intersections resolved by the code",intersections);
    map.fire("rectangle_query_results", {
        data: intersections
    });
};

var promises = checkIntersectionWithAllLayers(rectFeature);
promises
    .then(resolveIntersections)
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.error(error, '\n', error.stack);
    });
```

This code works,I want to get the promise working:

```
console.log("The result for layerLabel",result.layerLabel,"is ",result);
```

This code is never called:

```
console.log("The intersections resolved by the code",intersections);
```

The Chrome Devtools `Promises` tab does not seem to capture the information from this promise.

Comment: Build an [MCVE](/help/mcve). You'll probably figure out the problem while doing so, and if you don't, you'll have a nice, clear example for people to help you with. There's far too much unrelated code above.

Comment: How often is `callWorker` invoked (how many items are in that array it `map`s over), and how often do you get the result? `Q.all` does expect all of the promises to be resolved, not only some of them.

Comment: @Bergi The layerInfo.get() returns an array,the size of which cannot be predicted,i am testing it to work with 2 elements now.All the promises have to be resolved and the result of all the promises is passed to another component to build the UI..thus I am using `Q.all` and I would like to obtain the result as an Array,so it is preferred over `Q.allSettled`..I have `console.count` in `callWorker`, it is executed twice.

Comment: Yes, but you're getting the `console.log("The result for layerLabel", …` thing only once, don't you?

Comment: @Bergi that is correct,i only get the response message for the second element in the array.I added a `layerLabel` string to each one of these to make them unique,but I still get only one response message.

Comment: Then it's no wonder that `Q.all` doesn't resolve. You'll need to fix your web worker code.

Comment: @Bergi there was an additional call to `worker.postMessage`,I have two messages to `console.log("The result for layerLabel", …` but the promise is not resolved and the resolveIntresections is not called.